# hover hit areas moves

Tags: javascript, css, show-hide

Im trying to make a little animated div appear when the user mouses over a button. I have it working however, when you hover the button, it moves out of the hit area and closes again straight away.

Anyone know how to stop this happening? or suggest a better way to do it?

code and example here...

http://jsfiddle.net/PnUmM/132/

Answer (score 1):

If you pass only one function to `hover` as an argument this function is executed on hover-in and on hover-out. Try to use `mouseover` instead of `hover`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mouseleave, mounseenter events instead of hover. Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/7bSXb/.